# Вызов функции в стороннем ActionScript из C#

Tags: c#, функции, actionscript

Сабж, дело в том, что доступа к редактированию as-кода у меня нет, поэтому добавить в код нужные для внешнего вызова колбеки я не могу. Можно ли это как-то обойти? Может существуют какие-нибудь "грязные хаки" для этого?

Comment: А как, собственно, вы на данный момент его запускаете?

Comment: Он запускается в swf файле, расположенном на страничке в браузере. Собственно мне нужно вызывать некоторые его методы. Фактические - интересует результат их работы

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать подгрузить ваш swf в другой swf и уже там пощупать. Но не факт, что из этого что-то выйдет.